# DataFrame.from_records convert (Django) datetime to datetime64: Value Error

Tags: python, django, datetime, pandas

My error relates to datetime conversion on constructing a Pandas `DataFrame` after I upgraded to pandas 0.81.  Specifically, the *.from_records()* method passing a Django Queryset with timezone aware datetimes throws a datetime64 conversion error:

```
type(data)
> django.db.models.query.QuerySet

dv = data.values('begin_time', 'datum')
dv[0]
> {'begin_time': datetime.datetime(2006, 4, 27, 12, 40, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'datum': Decimal('13.3097500')}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( dv, index='begin_time' )
> ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64
  unless utc=True
```

The Django datetime is timezone aware and looks to me that it is set to UTC, so I find the error message a little cryptic, but that is probably my failing.   I'm relatively knew to Python.

So, I'm thinking that either I need to:
1. Somewhere set utc=true as the error says but I don't know where to exactly or
2. Switch off conversion to datetime64 in .from_records, but I also don't know where.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue here: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1825. I was just working on this stuff recently and apparently broke it (unless it works on git master now).

Comment: To follow up, verified fixed as of 9/10 and will be in next pandas release.

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering an bug in pandas 0.8.1 in parsing timezones: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1693

Marked as an enhancement, so maybe I'm not understanding and there could be a workaround, but I'm pretty sure it's just a bug. Already fixed but will have to wait for 0.8.2.
This works in 0.8.0 (I ran into the same error only after upgrading). You can try falling back to 0.8.0:

```
pip install -I pandas==0.8.0
```

As long as 0.8.0 still satisfies requirements of anything else that is using pandas in your app.

Or you might try to get the lastest from https://github.com/pydata/pandas and build it, but might be less stable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I've started to follow pandas on github but for now, I'll just roll back.

Comment: Encountered same/similar bug in DataFrame.from_items(). Building from github master branched fixed the problem (pandas.__version__ is 0.8.2.dev-859aa2c in my build).